# ¿cómo concatenar valores en un mismo campo al hacer update?

Tags: sql, sql-server

En un proceso, tengo una tabla en donde voy actualizando el campo `[CAMPO_ACTUALIZA]`, la condición no la nombro para no sacar la vista del problema.

1. `update [TABLA1] Set [CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] = 'COLOR_ROJO'`

Luego el proceso realiza otras tareas y dependiendo de esas tarea actualiza nuevamente ese campo

2. `update [TABLA1] Set [CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] = 'COLOR_AMARILLO'`

Se van repitiendo para cada registro, la cantidad de actualizaciones es indistinto para cada registro, algunos con 1 actualización, la mayoría entre 5 a 10 actualizaciones y algunos pueden llegar a ser actualizados 30 veces en el transcurso del proceso

3. `update [TABLA1] Set [CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] = 'COLOR_VERDE'`
4. `update [TABLA1] Set [CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] = 'COLOR_AMARILLO'`

El `update` va pisando el valor anterior, yo lo que pretendo es que no lo pise, sino que se concatenen, además estoy hablando de muchos registros, yo estoy poniendo un ejemplo de cuatro actualizaciones pero pueden tener hasta 30 actualizaciones con valor diferente o similares en el transcurso del proceso.

Resultado actual: `[CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] = 'COLOR_AMARILLO'`

Resultado esperado: `[CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] = 'COLOR_ROJO - COLOR_AMARILLO - COLOR_VERDE - COLOR_AMARILLO'`

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Omitir el hecho que la clausula `update` tiene condiciones hace parecer que todas las filas de la tabla van a recibir los valores. Creo que conviene añadir ese hecho, no hace falta escribir la condición real de cada actualización, pero si que cada `update` tiene un `where` distinto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada vez que ejecutes la sentencia `update` puedes concatenar el valor actual del campo. Para hacer esto debes tener en cuenta el tratamiento del valor `null`, ya que `null + 'cualquier cosa'` da como resultado `null`.

Hay dos posibles soluciones:

- Tener una columna `not null` e inicializarla con una cadena vacía `''`
- Aplicar funciones que nos ayuden a trabajar con el null, tales como `coalesce` y `nullif`, teniendo en cuenta que esto va a tener un impacto en el desempeño (puede ser que el impacto sea mínimo, habría que medirlo).

El primer caso es el más sencillo, simplemente lanzas las actualizaciones así:

```
update MiTabla set [campo actualiza] = [campo actualiza] + ' - color amarillo' where condiciones;
-- ejecutas parte del proceso y llegado el momento, actualizas de nuevo
update MiTabla set [campo actualiza] = [campo actualiza] + ' - color rojo' where condiciones;
-- y otra parte del proceso
update MiTabla set [campo actualiza] = [campo actualiza] + ' - color verde' where condiciones;
```

Al final, las filas que hayan coincidido con las condiciones todas las veces, tendrán todos los valores, mientras que las que hayan coincidido en uno o dos casos, tendrán esos valores nada más.

En el segundo caso, dado que el valor inicial puede ser `null`, hay que considerarlo, así:

```
update MiTabla set [campo actualiza] = coalesce([campo actualiza], '') + ' - color amarillo' where condiciones;
-- ejecutas parte del proceso y llegado el momento, actualizas de nuevo
update MiTabla set [campo actualiza] = coalesce([campo actualiza], '') + ' - color rojo' where condiciones;
-- y otra parte del proceso
update MiTabla set [campo actualiza] = coalesce([campo actualiza], '') + ' - color verde' where condiciones;
```

En los dos casos, al final algunos valores podrían quedar con un pequeño fallo, que es tener un espacio y guión al inicio, que estaría de más, para corregirlo, puedes correr esta última sentencia

```
update MiTabla 
  set [campo actualiza] = substring([campo actualiza], 4, 8000)
where [campo actualiza] like ' - %'
```

Como ya he dicho, considero que vale la pena correrla solo al final, asumiendo que no habrá consultas intermedias al valor almacenado en el `[campo actualiza]`. Si las hubiera, entonces se puede corregir en el mismo `update`, pero dejo eso como ejercicio para el autor para no hacer más larga esta respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias opciones.

1. Antes de hacer la actualización, consulta el valor actual del campo y le concatenas el nuevo valor:

   `UPDATE [TABLA1] SET [CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] = CONCAT('COLOR_AMARILLO', ' - ', (SELECT [CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] FROM [TABLA1] WHERE...)) WHERE...`
2. No actualizar el campo, en su lugar hacer un `insert` diferente cada vez que haya un cambio y relacionarlo de alguna manera, con un identificador o por fecha... algún campo que los relacione. Luego haces la consulta por el campo relacionado y concatenas los valores de `[CAMPO_ACTUALIZA]` al momento de mostrarlos.

   `SELECT [CAMPO_ACTUALIZA] FROM [TABLA1] WHERE [CAMPO_RELACIONADO] = 'VALOR_DEL_CAMPO'`

Finalmente, iteras los resultados con un ciclo para mostrar los valores concatenados.